# perform an calculation of: the average of the average by month of each category in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python im developing an RFV analysis, the frequency is the average of the total times the category was used in a month, during all the months

so:

| Category | Average used |
| --- | --- |
| A - jan | 10 |
| A - feb | 12 |
| A - mar | 14 |
| total average | 12 |

so for the option A in table will be 12, and this must comes inside this:

```
df2 = df = df.groupby('category').agg({
'date' : lambda x: (dt_ref - x.max()).days,
'id_licenca' : lambda x: len(x)

})
```

the other two funcions are ok, but i need that after the id_licenca line, the final result will be something like (only describing the need for the frequency)

| Category | Average used |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| B | 17 |
| C | 11 |

*i need the whole calculation for that*

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass specially reserved strings to calculate some of the common aggreagation, in this case `'mean'`.

```
df2 = df.groupby('category').agg({
    'date': lambda x: (dt_ref - x.max()).days,
    'id_licenca': 'count',
    'average_used': 'mean'
})
```

By the way, you don't even need `lambda` for calculating the size of the group, you can just use `'count'`.

Comment: I meant, this average must be an average by year, the average of the average by year, the average used must be from a count of the categories....that is hard to explain, sorry